# Have to click twice to submit the form in IE8

Tags: html, forms

A very peculiar bug in a simple html form. After changing an option, button has to be clicked twice to submit the form. Button is focused after clicking once, but form is not submitted. It's only this way in IE8 and works fine in Chrome and FF.

PAY ATTENTION TO 'g^' right before `<select>`. It has to be a letter or number followed by a symbol to generate this bug. For example, 'a#','f$','3(' all create the same bug. Otherwise it works fine. BTW, if you don't change option and click button right away,there won't be any bug.

Very strange, huh?

```
<form method="post" action="match.php">
g^
<select>
<option>Select</option>
<option>English</option>
<option>French</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/vCdpN/ Also I'd suggest to validate. There are many unnecessary errors in there.

Comment: Is the JSFiddler example broken in IE8 for you, too?

Comment: @RoToRa I run the script on JsFiddle by IE8, it works. It is just getting me more confused. What's happening on my IE8? What setting could possibly trigger this bug?

Comment: Is there anything else on the page that you left out for your example?

Comment: I keep the html form and cut out everything else, and bug is still there. See the modified post please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am providing the code here, which is working fine. Check this code whether this code also is giving you the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title> Sample page for language selection </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<style type="text/css">
    p{display: none;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // language as an array
        var language = ['Arabic', 'Cantonese', 'Chinese', 'English', 'French', 'German', 'Greek', 'Hebrew', 'Hindi', 'Italian', 'Japanese', 'Korean', 'Malay', 'Polish', 'Portuguese', 'Russian', 'Spanish', 'Thai', 'Turkish', 'Urdu', 'Vietnamese'];

        $('#muyu').append('<option value=0>Select</option>');

        //loop through array
        for (i in language)  //js unique statement for iterate array
        { 

        $('#muyu').append($('<option>', { id: 'muyu' + i, val: language[i], html: language[i] })) }

        $('form').submit(function() {
            // alert('I am being called!');  // check if submit event is triggered
            if ($('#muyu').val() == 0) { $('#muyu_error').show(); } else { $('#muyu_error').hide(); return true; }
            return false;
        });
    })
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="PostProb">
        I am fluent in <select name='muyu' id='muyu'></select>
        <p id='muyu_error'>Tell us your native language</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But it is not working on my IE8... Could there be any IE settings trigger this bug?

Comment: I just posted my code. Check it. Make sure you change the action attribute of form.

Comment: I copy your code and run it on my IE8. The bug is still exactly the same.

Comment: I revised the post significantly.